# Uniform continuity and existence of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$
$\newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon}$

I have a hard time proving or disproving the following (seemingly simple) proposition:

$f:[0,b) \rightarrow \R$ is uniformly continuous. Then, $\lim_{t \nearrow b}{f(t)}$ exists. Furthermore, the extension $g$ of $f$ on $[0,b]$ with the limit value added at $b$ is uniformly continuous.

I first tried using sequences. This is the summary of the attemption: Let $(x_k)_{k\in \N} \subseteq [0,b)$ be a sequence that converges to $b$. Then, I showed that $(f(x_k))_{k\in\N}$ is Cauchy from uniform continuity. Therefore, for every such sequence, $c=\lim f(x_k)$ exists and we can also show that the limit value $c$ does not depend on $x_k$. Finally, assuming that the extension $g$ with $g(b) = c$ is discontinuous at $b$ yields a contradiction.

But the proof is excessively complex than I expected. I believe there is a much simpler way to show this. Or is there a theorem that can be used for this?

Definitions:

Uniform continuity: $\forall \eps > 0: \exists \delta > 0:\forall s,t \in [0,b): |s-t| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(s) - f(t)| < \eps$

Existence of limit: $\exists c > 0:\forall\eps > 0:\exists \delta > 0:\forall s \in [0,b):|s-b| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(s) - c| < \eps$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing existence of limit in $b$ point let's use [Caushy criterion for function limit existence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569036/how-to-prove-cauchy-criterion-for-limits) :

limit of $f(x)$ in point $b$ exists if and only if for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $x,y$ with $0<|x-b|$ ,$|y-b|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

Let's take any $\varepsilon>0$. As you have written from uniform continuity we have some $\delta>0$, such that $\forall s,t \in [0,b): |s-t| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(s) - f(t)| < \varepsilon$. If we consider $s,t$ for which $0<|s-b|$ ,$|t-b|<\frac{\delta}{2}$, then for such $s,t$ we have $|s-t| < \delta$, so from uniform continuity we obtain Caushy criterion, so, we obtain existence of limit $\lim\limits_{x\to b}f(x)$. Let's denote this limit by $f(b)$, which gives, that we extend our function continuosly on $[0,b]$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you find a textbook reference for the Cauchy criterion for functions?

Comment: John M.H. Olmsted - Advanced calculus-Prentice Hall (1961), pages 60-61.